# Dúvida no insert, update e delete com Framework CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, codeigniter

Tenho uma dúvida relacionado a inserção, alteração e remoção dos registros no banco de dados MySql. Por exemplo, imagine uma tabela de notas, onde são cadastradas todas as informações dessa nota, como os dados do fornecedor, os dados da transportadora e os impostos a recolher. E temos também uma tabela nota_itens, onde será inseridos os itens dessa nota. Pois bem, no PHP estruturado, eu faria da seguinte maneira: Primeiro eu faria um INSERT para cadastrar os dados da tabela nota e depois eu faria um outro INSERT para cadastrar os dados da tabela nota_itens com o ultimo id da tabela nota na tabela nota_itens referenciando então as duas tabelas. A minha dúvida é a seguinte, no Framework CodeIgniter existe algum mecanismo ou função que faça isso automaticamente? Ou eu terei que implementar a mesma ideia do PHP estruturado? Espero ter sido claro em minha dúvida e desde já agradeço!

Comment: @Gwer é boa sua iniciativa de ajudar a melhorar os posts. Fica a sugestão de aproveitar nestes casos e quebrar melhor os parágrafos, e acertar também nomenclaturas de palavras chave e termos técnicos, etc. Para mais detalhes de formatação, caso você não conheça os detalhes, veja este link: **[Ajuda do Markdown](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/markdown)** e também aqui: **[Como devemos formatar perguntas e respostas?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1084/)**

Comment: @Bacco Ok, obrigado pela sugestão! Estou a pouco tempo aqui no fórum. Fico feliz de ajudar, e vou melhorar isso sim. ;)

Comment: @GWER não sei se você percebeu que diversas edições suas estão sendo rejeitadas e as que são aprovadas precisam de melhorias. Então faça uma revisão no que você está editando para ver onde você está falhando e possa melhorar. Como já foi dito, a iniciativa é boa mas as edições precisam ser substanciais e devem realmente melhorar a postagem. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/22780/gwer?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que não tenha como, você terá que fazer os dois inserts, fica até mais fácil utilizando as funções passadas pelo Andrew Maxwell e GWER

Answer (score 0):

Tente utilizar o `last_insert_id()`;

A função do MySQL `last_insert_id()` retorna o último inteiro criado para uma coluna *auto_increment* de uma tabela. Este inteiro está disponível no cache de memória que o MySQL utiliza para armazenar os valores da coluna *auto_increment*, assim gerando a sequência.

Veja aqui : http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-insert-id.php

PDO: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Comment: Bom dia @Guilherme Wermann, acho que vc tbm não entendeu a minha pergunta. A minha dúvida é sobre como inserir, alterar ou deletar dados em duas ou mais tabelas relacionadas em codeigniter? Vc tem ideia de como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Creio que não é possível, você teria que fazer dois inserts.

Answer (score 0):

Tem sim colega, tem uma função do banco de dados que faz esse procedimento `$this->db->insert_id()`, ela pega o último id cadastrado no banco de dados. Vlw

Comment: Bom dia @AndrewMaxwell, acho que vc não entendeu a minha pergunta. A minha dúvida é sobre como inserir, alterar ou deletar dados em duas ou mais tabelas relacionadas em codeigniter? Vc tem ideia de como posso fazer isso?